# MySQL logic/numeric constraints?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm new to MySQL and relational databases.
I'm trying to create a little soccer info website and I'm getting started with database design using PhpMyAdmin.
For now I got two tables, 'team' and 'match';
I want the 'goals' field of 'team' to be automatically updated when a new row of match (which obviously includes the goals scored by the team in that match) is added into the database, is it possible?
It would be useful because I'd use it for lots of fields (number of yellow-red cards, points in the competition table...)
Thanks!!!

Comment: You could use `SQL Triggers` for an `ON INSERT` event to automate the subsequent update event. Tutorial here -> http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-the-first-trigger-in-mysql.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you shouldn't have a table named `match` since it is a keyword in MySQL. Name it `matches` instead.

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_goals
AFTER INSERT ON matches
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE team SET goals = goals + NEW.goals 
WHERE team_id = NEW.team_id;
```

This is called a trigger. It is called whenever you insert into the `matches` tables, and it will increment the `goal` attribute in `team` table for that particular team by the value of `goal` that you are adding to `matches`.

Note that the NEW keyword indicates the row that you are inserting into `matches`.

Comment: +1 . . . Especially for pointing out that `match` is a reserved word and offering a better name.

Comment: Thanks, it's perfect! Anyway "match" was only a fictitious name, I didn't use it.